# Trouble trying to eliminate a node from a tree (struct)

Tags: c, struct, tree

As the title says I'm trying to remove a node from a tree having 2 cases:

- the node is a leaf that not connected to anything
- the node is connected to another node

I was able to make a working function for the second case (the most difficult for me), but the first one (that seemed easy) causes a segmentation fault no matter what I try.

Here is the definition of struct:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *sx;
    struct node *dx;
};

typedef struct node *tree;
```

Here is the module that perform the operation of elimination:

```
void destroy_node(tree Y, int elem) {
    if (Y->value < elem)
        destroy_node(Y->dx, elem);
    if (Y->value > elem)
        destroy_node(Y->sx, elem);
    else { //
        if (Y->sx == NULL && Y->dx == NULL) {
            free(Y); <-- seg fault
            Y = NULL; <-- seg fault
        }
        if (Y->sx != NULL && Y->dx == NULL) {
            Y->value = (Y->sx)->value;
            free(Y->sx);
            Y->sx = NULL;
        }
        if (Y->sx == NULL && Y->dx != NULL) {
            Y->value = (Y->dx)->value;
            free(Y->dx);
            Y->dx = NULL;
        }
        if (Y->sx != NULL && Y->dx != NULL)
            printf("Can't eliminate that!\n");
    }
    print_everything(Y);
}
```

Here is the `main` call:

```
tree Y = T;
printf("Which one you want to destroy?  ");
scanf("%d", &elem);
destroy_node(Y, elem);
```

To compile the function I use the command

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra c.c
```

My environment is a virtual machine ubuntu 17.04 with stock gcc

**EDIT 1**

Module that build a tree

```
tree insert_node(tree T, int val) {
    if (T == NULL) {    
        T = (tree)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        T->value = val;
        T->sx = NULL;
        T->dx = NULL;
    } else {
        if ((T->value) < (val)) {
            T->dx = insert_node(T->dx, val);
        }
        if ((T->value) > (val)) {
            T->sx = insert_node(T->sx, val);
        }
    }
    return T;
}
```

Here there is the call in the main of this module

```
printf("How many nodes your tree will have?  ");
scanf("%d", &tot);
for (int i = 0; i < tot; i++) {
    printf("What is the %d° node?  ", (i + 1));
    scanf("%d", &val);
    T = insert_node(T, val);
}
```

P.S. If there are problem regarding the comprehensibility of the program I will copy paste the whole file

Comment: Can you add the part where you build the tree?

Comment: @atru inserted the other function that you requested hope it helps

Comment: You forgot to check that `Y` is not null.

Comment: Hiding pointers behind typedefs? Ew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are missing pieces in your function:

- You do not check if `Y != NULL`.  You would have undefined behavior on an empty tree.
- There is a missing else after the first `if` statement. You mistakenly delete the node if `Y->value <= elem`.
- You do not update the parent pointer when you delete a node.

You should change the API to return the updated value for the pointer argument:

```
tree destroy_node(tree Y, int elem) {
    tree res = Y;
    if (Y != NULL) {
        if (Y->value < elem) {
            Y->dx = destroy_node(Y->dx, elem);
        } else
        if (Y->value > elem) {
            Y->sx = destroy_node(Y->sx, elem);
        } else {
        if (Y->dx == NULL) {
            res = Y->sx;
            free(Y);
        } else
        if (Y->sx == NULL) {
            res = Y->dx;
            free(Y);
        } else {
            printf("Can't eliminate that!\n");
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Call from `main` as:

```
tree T;
...
printf("Which one you want to destroy? ");
if (scanf("%d", &elem) == 1)
    T = destroy_node(T, elem);
```

Of course you must find a solution to delete nodes with 2 branches.

Comment: Using this instantly made my code works. Obviously i will found a solution to delete node with 2 branches but i usually try to start from a small code working and then adding new function to avoid too much confusion(and error). Btw thanks

Comment: @Allen: that's a good approach. Re-reading the code, I realized the `if (Y->sx == NULL && Y->dx == NULL)` test is redundant. Answer updated and simplified.